# Rails 4.1.15 PostgreSQL, update to numeric(9) field gives "No integer type has byte size 9"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is driving us nuts.

We recently added a numeric(9,0) field (call it 'foo') to a table via Rails migration. Now, an attempt to update this field gives:

```
irb(main):001:0> e = MyModel.first
irb(main):002:0> e.foo = 1
irb(main):003:0> e.save!
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
(0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: No integer type has byte size 9. Use a numeric with precision 0 instead.
```

It's apparently deciding the type is integer and taking the precision value as the length (byte-size) for an integer.

We stripped the model down to basically class ... end without making it go away.

Same error with PG 8.4 and 9.1.

We can add an identical field to another table and it works there, but not in this one.

Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Update:
Interestingly, the table in which the numeric(9) field CAN be updated, lacked a lock_version field. Adding lock_version to that table enabled optimistic locking and suddenly the problem shows up there. Turning off optimistic locking on the originally failing table also works. Don't have a clue why yet.

Comment: Have you done something like [this](https://ariejan.net/2012/08/28/rails-migrations-decimal-precision-and-scale/)?

Comment: Yes, we tried making it just numeric, and then it complains that 0 is not a valid length for an integer type (IIRC). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How specifically did you add a `numeric(9,0)` column? What does `\d table_name` say from inside `psql`?

Comment: apparently active record has no prevision for this case.  Just a wild idea: use a before save callback to save as float or number_with_precision(not sure how this works)  if fixnun has been provided

Comment: The field was created via an add_column migration with type :numeric and precision: 9. It's typed to match another database that the data will be coming from. Inspecting the tables and fields in PGAdmin shows no detectable difference between the working and non-working cases, and the types show as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, the table in which the numeric(9) field CAN be updated, lacked a lock_version field. Adding lock_version to that table enabled optimistic locking and suddenly the problem shows up there. Turning off optimistic locking on the originally failing table also works. Don't have a clue why yet.